# Amazon FPS in Rails with Remit doesn't work without the sandbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sandbox, amazon-fps

I am new to Amazon Flexible Payment Service(FPS). I implemented FPS in Ruby On Rails utilizing a gem called [Remit](https://github.com/tylerhunt/remit). I made FPS work in the [sandbox](https://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/overview), where I can see all fake transactions with a status of completed. However, no transactions can come into my FPS Account Activity after I switching off the sandbox. What might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Add some code or explain better.